# While trying to work on the questionbelow on asp.net using linq sql it is not diplaying the any results

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-like

The question is

1. Display book where names start with “s”

   ```
   public ActionResult quesTwo()
   {


       var name = from s in obj.Table_1s where s.title=="s%" select s;

       return View(name);
   }
   ```

But while using the like function I'm getting error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBztp.png)

Comment: *while using the like function* -- There is no `like` function in LINQ. I can't help feeling that you're just haphazardly trying something without seeing any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

here is how to use like in linq :

Operator         Description

- Contains()     It is equivalent to `like '%string%'`
- StartsWith()   It is equivalent to `like 'string%'`
- EndsWith()    It is equivalent to `like '%string'`

in your case :

```
var name = from s in obj.Table_1s where s.title.StartsWith("s") select s;
```